# Why don't I get Index Seek for my non-clustered index

Tags: index, azure-sql-managed-instance

Version: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   (Azure Managed Instance)

I'm working with a table (ActivityAttributes) that has ~190Mn rows. I've created an Index as below.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ActivityAttributes_namevalue_new] ON [dbo].[ActivityAttributes]
(
    [Activity_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE([name],[value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And my query is

```
select
  name,
  value
from ActivityAttributes
where value = 'Apps'
  and [name] = 'New Status'
```

And my table looks like this,

| name | Activity_id | value | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New Status | 140737 | Member | 7051743 |
| New Status | 1512010 | Apps | 705211747 |
| New Status | 1595147 | Apps | 705112750 |

The execution plan I get for this query is,
[image]

My problem is why it does Index Scans even though I used the included fields in the predicate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Heads up for future reference, SQL Server is not the same as Azure SQL Managed Instance (I fixed your title and tags accordingly). Also, please don't use screenshots to show the execution plan, as it doesn't show all the information that the plan contains. It's better to upload the plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and add the link to it in your Post instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seeks only happen on Key fields [Activity_Id], Include (covering) columns are used to minimise Key/Rid lookups.

This index will give you a Seek (Range Seek because it's non-unique):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ActivityAttributes_namevalue_new] ON [dbo].[ActivityAttributes]
(
   [name] ASC
  ,[value] ASC
)
INCLUDE( [Activity_id]) 
GO
```

The order of the Key columns is important. Whichever column has the most unique values should be first. However if it's an Inequality i.e. `[Date] >= xxx` then any key columns after the `[Date]` field will be not be seeked (only a Residual Predicate).